# How can I work with Apache Flink to detect fraud with data taken from diferent topics from kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, complex-event-processing, flink-cep

I'm new with apache flink and I need to implement a fraud detector with fixed time.

Basically what I need is to take data from 3 topics from kafka (UserAuthentication,PasswordChanged and SafeTransaction).

when I get events of userAuthentication and passwordChanged wait for 5 minutes, if a safeTransaction confirmation was not received in that 5 minutes I need to launch a fraud alert.

I have been reading about PatternAPI used in apache flink to do CEP but I couldn't find any example taking data from different topics and finding a similar pattern as mine in data.

I will be grateful for getting any suggestion to approach this problem.

p.s: I'm not an English native speaker, so I apologize beforehand if my grammar and redaction is not clear

Comment: You need event time or processing time ?

Comment: @AntonioMiranda I need event time

Comment: Wait for 5 minutes in event time may be difficult if you are waiting for some events. I will supose one scenario:
You have your events, and now you are waiting for the safeTransaction , but it never comes ( because its a fraud ). Well , in event time , the fraud alert never be trigger ! Because the event time are stucked in the last event timestamp ... have you thought about that problem?